# glue maps not returning record when using isdigit() function in glue map transform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to call a map. apply to transform on dynamic frames in AWS glue which will create a new column in the dynamic frame and populates its value based on whether my other column is a digit or not.

I have created a data frame and converted it into a dynamic frame and then call map. apply. I have created a python definition which will check whether the column is a digit or not and passed it to map.apply.But after applying this map rec is returning null.

```
def isDigit(rec):
    if rec["_4"]:
        rec["hey"] =1
    return rec

l = [('1','125','REF123','1.5','Normal','Diagonose','12 12 2018'),('2','124','REF1234','1.7','Critical','Report','14 Mar 2019'),
    ('3',None,'REF1234','1.8','Critical','Report','12 Jan 2018')]
source_file = sc.parallelize(l)

source_file = source_file.toDF()
source_file  = DynamicFrame.fromDF(source_file, glueContext, "datasource1")
mapped_dyF = Map.apply(frame = source_file, f = isDigit)
mapped_dyF.toDF().show()
```

[image]

Above code worked fine but while I am using isDigit() its no records in returned

```
While using isDigit() it reuturn null 
def isDigit(rec):
    **if rec["_4"].isDigit():**
        rec["hey"] =1
    return rec
```

[image]

I want to get the value of 1 in hey column if column _4 is a digit.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a string from the record field. Try if below work. use python isdigit() function. The function name is all small letter.

```
def isDigit(rec):
  check = str(rec["_4"])
  if check.isdigit():
    rec["hey"] =1
  return rec
```